# saving two array in database pdo from ajax

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax, pdo

I want to insert two array together with other values in database currently i am saving them using `bindValue` and using foreach to iterate on the two array.

Ajax

```
$rows.each(function() {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    var namesport = $tds.eq(0).text();
    var time = $tds.eq(1).text();
    var date = $tds.eq(2).text();
    valueToPush1.push({
        sportname: namesport,
        time: time,
        date: date,

    });
});

var valueToPush = [];
$rows.each(function() {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    var subjectname = $tds.eq(0).text();
    var time = $tds.eq(1).text();
    var date = $tds.eq(2).text();
    valueToPush.push({
        namesubject: subjectname,
        time: time,
        date: date,

    });
});
var sports = JSON.stringify(valueToPush);
var class = JSON.stringify(valueToPush1);
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../include/studentactivities.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                id: studentid,
                sports: sports,
                class: class,

            },
```

from this ajax i send it to php where i do the inserting of files. This is where i am stuck for i run out of ideas how to save these two array together with other information. I save these two array in each respective tables as follows

php

```
    $sports = ($_POST['sports']);
    $sportsjson = json_decode(stripslashes($sports), true);

    $class = ($_POST['class']);
    $classjson = json_decode(stripslashes($class), true);
    $id = ($_POST['id']);
    if (isset($id)) {
        $sportsarray = array();
        $classarray = array();
        foreach($sports as $value) {
                $sportsarray[] = array(
                    'sport' => $value['sportname'],
                    'stime' => $value['time'],
                    'sdate' => $value['date']);
                }
                foreach($classjson as $value1) {
                    $classarray[] = array(
                        'subject' => $value1['subjectname'],
                        'ctime' => $value1['time'],
                        'cdate' => $value1['date']);
                    }

                    $aray = array_merge($sportsarray, $classjson);
                    //echo json_encode($aray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                    foreach($aray as $value) {
                        $stmt = $dbh - > prepare("INSERT INTO sports_tbl (sport_name,time,date) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                        $stmt - > bindValue(1, $value['sport'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt - > bindValue(2, $value['stime'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt - > bindValue(3, $value['sdate'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);

                        $stmt1 = $dbh - > prepare("INSERT INTO class_tbl (class_name,time,date) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                        $stmt1 - > bindValue(1, $value['class'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt1 - > bindValue(2, $value['ctime'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt1 - > bindValue(3, $value['cdate'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        if ($stmt - > execute() && $stmt1 - > execute()) {
                            echo json_encode($aray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                        } else {
                            echo "Not added";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The problem is i get error. When i remove the insert sql and return `json_eoncode` i get double result. What is the cleaner way to do this kind of insert in pdo

Comment: This should be a parse error: `$stmt1 - > bindValue(...)`  The arrow operator can't have whitespace between `-` and `>`:  `$stmt->bindValue(..)`  Make sure you are developing and testing code with `display_errors` enabled in php.ini, and `error_reporting = E_ALL`. PHP should be complaining about this....

Comment: it doesnt have white space in my code sorry maybe it got that space when i use this http://jsbeautifier.org/ to arrange the code. when i paste it here.